# Jquery tabs and html lists

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have tabs and a list in my code. I am using jquery for tabs. The code is :

```
<div id ="xvz">
<!--list one here-->
   <ul>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
   <ul>
<!--list for tabs here-->
   <ul>
      <li>tab 1</li>
      <li>tab 2</li>
   <ul>
</div>
```

in js file ,

```
$("#xyz").tabs();
```

This code makes the first list as a tabbed list and the second one is a plain html list. What should i do so that the second one is the tabbed one. One solution is putting the second list in a div element and then applying tab function to it. But I dont want to touch my html code. Is there a way I can do it simply by making js changes.
Thanks in advance

Comment: show us the structure of the list one and two

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the plugin should be used. If it should be called on the list container you can do the following:

```
// get the second list and wrap it into div#listWrapper
$("#xyz ul").eq(1).wrap('<div id="listWrapper"></div>');

// activate tabs on the list inside our new wrapper
$('#listWrapper').tabs();
```

If it can be called on the list itself then you can simply do:

```
$("#xyz ul").eq(1).tabs();
```

*edit*

If you do not want to change your html code even using javascript you can change it only at the time of tabs initialization:

```
var $xyz = $("#xyz");
var $firstUl = $xyz.find("ul").eq(0);
var $secondUl = $xyz.find("ul").eq(1);

// swap lists:
$xyz.append($firstUl);

// init tabs
$xyz.tabs();

// swap again
$xyz.prepend($firstUl);
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you seems to be out of luck as the plugin seems to be fetching the first `ol,ul` element to created the tabs

```
_getList: function() {
    return this.element.find( "ol,ul" ).eq( 0 );
},
```

Comment: How did you know which tab plugin is used?